# Installing laravel in a subfolder, NOT subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, subdomain

I've been trying to find guides/blogs/posts/comments online for this simple question but to no avail. I simply want my laravel installed here  `http://blabla.bla/SUBFOLDER` and accessed just like it is without specifying an index.php etc. I can't stand the fact that printing any sort of variables through `.htaccess` is also not easily doable so that I can learn and improvise a solution. Which is what brings me here.

My domain root directory is like so -

```
var/Laravel-Private/
var/www/
       /<main project>
       /SUBFOLDER/<symlink to var/Laravel-Private/public>
```

Comment: What web engine are you using?

Comment: @Charlie My website is hosted with namecheap, I think they're using apache.

Comment: What problem are you going to solve with laravel being one level deep in the domain path?

Comment: @Mjh You just said it yourself. I want it to be one level deep and not the root. So I can host multiple apps on the same domain without making subdomains for each.

Comment: @SagunKho - but did you ever consider how laravel works and why it expects to be at the top level? I don't think you considered what other approaches there are, so you ended up with an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your solution to multitenancy interferes with the framework and how it's supposed to be used. You most likely don't even need multiple laravels, but only one. Subdomain solution is an elegant way to use multiple laravel installations, I assume you have a reason why you want to avoid it, but what you have in mind won't work.

Comment: @Mjh This doesn't have anything to do with multi-tenancy, I'm not hosting multiple tenants. Just 2 different projects, one in a sub folder. All I think it needs is an htaccess rewrite rule to make sure it falls back on the subdomain, while in the subdomain's uri for every call.

Comment: Best of luck with your endeavors. If all you think it needs is .htaccess rewrite rule, then all you need to do is do it.

Comment: @Mjh I suppose you're right about it being a framework limitation. But even though subdomains are the elegant way of managing this, I would have preferred sub-folders for my use-case.

Answer (score -1):

Just place your project outside of the web root (to prevent direct access to other files). Than inside your webroot add the directory SUBFOLDER and inside that directory add a new file called index.php and put this as the content:

```
<?php


 require_once '../../Laravel-Private/public/index.php';
```

Comment: Thanks but would this work if I had another “main” laravel project in the root folder?

Comment: Sure, do it the same way. with a index file that links to the real project outside your web root still.